# windows 10 compiled binding best practice

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to implement the new compiled binding in a windows 10 C# app, I followed MSVA videos and the binding work, but when I make some changes the UI doesn't update.
for example when I add a new profile in profilesView, or when I update a name in profileview.
here it is my code:

profile.cs

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

profileviewmodel.cs

```
public class ProfileViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Profile defaultProfile = new Profile { };
    public Profile DefaultProfile {
        get { return this.defaultProfile; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this.defaultProfile, value); }
    }
```

profilesviewmodel.cs

```
     public class ProfilesViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Profile> profiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile> { };
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> Profiles {
        get { return this.profiles; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this.profiles, value); }
    }
```

profilespage.xaml

```
    xmlns:vm="using:vCard.ViewModels">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ProfilesViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Profiles}" xmlns:model="using:vCard.Models">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Profile">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

profilespage.xaml.cs

```
  public ProfilesViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    public ProfilesPage2()
    {
        this.ViewModel = new ProfilesViewModel();

        this.InitializeComponent();            

        this.DataContextChanged += (s,e) => { ViewModel = DataContext as ProfilesViewModel; };            

        ViewModel.Profiles.Add(new Profile { Name = "aaa" });
    }
```

profilepage.xaml

```
xmlns:vm="using:vCard.ViewModels">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ProfileViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Profile" Margin="10"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding DefaultProfile.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="Name_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding DefaultProfile.Surname, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="Name_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding DefaultProfile.FullName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

profilepage.xaml.cs

```
    public ProfileViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    public ProfilePage2()
    {
        this.ViewModel = new ProfileViewModel();

        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Setup the DataContext 
        this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) => { ViewModel = DataContext as ProfileViewModel; };

        ViewModel.DefaultProfile.Name = "aaa";

    }
```

thanks

Comment: You don't update the datacontext but one of it's property. It don'est raise your event if the Profiles property doesn't  propagte the event. Did you link the changed event of the Profiles observable collection ?

Comment: Can you suggest your solution? i Just find out that if in the end I call 
            Bindings.Update(); 
it works

Comment: By calling Bindings.Update() you force the windows to rebind or check the bindings, all of them. By using the changed event of the ObservableCollection you can trigger you binding refresh just on this one and not all of them.

Comment: Can you kindly show me the code? in windows 8/8.1 I assigned datacontext = viewmodel and it worked automagically. thanks

Comment: I can't I lack data. Can you show us the ProfilesViewModel class please ?

Comment: I Added the code, I changed also the question, because I have a similar problem for the single profile view, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it based on your scenario. I bit different approach but clear enough to understand I hope:

profile.cs
*** use the implement the INotifyPropertyChanged only if you will bind the properties on UI controls

```
public class Profile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string name;
    public string surname;
    public string fullname;


    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    public string Surname { get { return surname; } set { surname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Surname"); } }

    public string FullName { get { return fullname; } set { fullname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Fullname"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

profileviewmodel.cs ** updated

```
public ObservableCollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set;}

public ProfilesViewModel()
{
    Profiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();
}
```

profilepage.xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <!-- The TwoWay binding is for updating the object through UI -->
                <!-- If you need TwoWay you must use TextBox not TextBlock -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

profilepage.xaml.cs

```
public ProfilesViewModel ViewModel = new ProfilesViewModel();
public ProfilePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = ViewModel;

    ViewModel.Profiles.Add(new Profile { Name = "aaa" });
    ViewModel.Profiles.Add(new Profile { Name = "bbb" });

}
```

Comment: Thanks I like this! ... and I found out that new compiled Binding (with x:bind) works, just cannot change value in constructor or in OnNavigateTo method because the viewmodel it's not initialized yet

Answer (score 0):

Try implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your code

profile.cs

```
public class Profile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string name = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
    private string surname = string.Empty;
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname; }
        set { surname = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Surname"); }
    }
    private string fullName = string.Empty;
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return fullName; }
        set { fullName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FullName"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but the problem persist, I was wondering what is the best practice if I want to use a database, use this approach or implement NotifyPropertyChanged for all parameters in the viewmodel?

Comment: Can you post the link of the videos you watched?. Also to use INotifyPropertyChanged I believe its not a bad practice. Add the event in all the items you changed programaticaty exept the ObservableCollection witch if I remember correctly has allready implement the notify changed.
also you can try the Bindings.Update() as mention in a comment above after you finish the changes.

Comment: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10 video N 4